# Julia Subtyp validation before the Subtype is instantiated

Tags: inheritance, julia, this, parent-child

I just need to call a validation_field() "this function will validate the child struct" on the subtype struct whenever the subtype is created and not when instantiated. so first how can I define the subtype in the  Supertype(is there any Base function like e.g. "getSubtype()"), is there any "this" keyword in julia and is there any alternative for my approche?

```
function validate_field(field::Model1)
    @assert typeof(attr)==float, "Validation error for type of default"
end

struct Model1

  validate_field("this")
end


struct G <: Model1
atrr::float 
end
```

Comment: So your question is "how do I programatically ensure that all subtypes of `Model1` only have float fields"?

Comment: Also, be aware that you are using terminology and concepts which don't exist in Julia. There is no concrete inheritance; and no concepts or difference between "creation" and "instantiation".

Comment: jep, you are totally right. I might used some concepts that dose not exist in Julia. but Im a bit lost with my approche. cause all what I wanna do is, just ensure that all subtypes have that attr of type Float when I subtyping (e.g in Java whenever the Child is created) and how could I define the Subtype in the Supertype

Comment: You should be aware that you cannot subtype concrete types, so it's not possible to have `G <: Model1`. `G`'s supertype must be abstract. If you need to operate on fields in a struct, you can use the `fieldnames` and `getfield` functions. But I suspect that you are trying to solve your problem in a way which is not optimal. Can you describe your larger goal?

Answer (score 4):

The validation function can be implemented via reflection:

```
julia> function validate_field(::Type{T}) where {T<:Model1}
           fieldtype(T, :attr) <: Float64 || error("`attr` has invalid field type")
       end
validate_field (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> validate_field(G)
true

julia> struct H <: Model1
           attr::Symbol
       end

julia> validate_field(H)
ERROR: `attr` has invalid field type
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(s::String)
   @ Base ./error.jl:33
 [2] validate_field(#unused#::Type{H})
   @ Main ./REPL[10]:2
 [3] top-level scope
   @ REPL[13]:1
```

The rest does not carry over from Java.  First, there is no concrete inheritance.  You can only have abstract supertypes, which can have no fields:

```
abstract type Model1 end
```

Then, methods are not associated with types, but with functions.  The same holds for constructors; so there is no inheritance of constructors, and no `this`.

You can approximately fulfill your requirements by doing something like the following:

```
julia> subtypes(Model1)
2-element Vector{Any}:
 G
 H

julia> foreach(validate_field, subtypes(Model1))
ERROR: `attr` has invalid field type
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(s::String)
   @ Base ./error.jl:33
 [2] validate_field(#unused#::Type{H})
   @ Main ./REPL[10]:2
 [3] foreach(f::typeof(validate_field), itr::Vector{Any})
   @ Base ./abstractarray.jl:2141
 [4] top-level scope
   @ REPL[15]:1
```

But this does only verify an unspecified set of subtypes existing at some specific point at runtime.

The much more Julian approach is to just pretend (by duck-typing) in the *consumers* of `Model1` child objects that they have an `attr` field of a type compatible with whatever they do:

```
somefunction(m::Model1) = m.attr^2
```

will work for anything for which an appropriate method of `^` exists.  If that doesn't work, you get a `MethodError` anyway, which is not worse than the error from `validate_field`.

Probably you should first go and get familiar with multiple dispatch, and Julia's idiomatic alternatives to object orientation, and then try to design your approach differently.

---

If you go crazy, you can use a kind of trait:

```
julia> HasAttr(::Type{T}) where {T} = Val{false}()
HasAttr (generic function with 1 method)

julia> HasAttr(::Type{T}) where {T<:Model1} = Val{fieldtype(T, :attr) <: Float64}()
HasAttr (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> @code_warntype HasAttr(G)
Variables
  #self#::Core.Const(HasAttr)
  #unused#::Core.Const(G)

Body::Val{true}
1 ─ %1 = Main.fieldtype($(Expr(:static_parameter, 1)), :attr)::Core.Const(Float64)
│   %2 = (%1 <: Main.Float64)::Core.Const(true)
│   %3 = Core.apply_type(Main.Val, %2)::Core.Const(Val{true})
│   %4 = (%3)()::Core.Const(Val{true}())
└──      return %4

julia> some_other_function(m) = some_other_function(m, HasAttr(typeof(m)))
some_other_function (generic function with 1 method)

julia> some_other_function(m, ::Val{true}) = missing
some_other_function (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> some_other_function(G(1.0))
missing

julia> some_other_function(H(:bla))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching some_other_function(::H, ::Val{false})
Closest candidates are:
  some_other_function(::Any) at REPL[23]:1
  some_other_function(::Any, ::Val{true}) at REPL[24]:1
Stacktrace:
 [1] some_other_function(m::H)
   @ Main ./REPL[23]:1
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[27]:1
```

But I can tell you already that this is not what you are really looking for...